# How to let element align and center without using align-items and justify-content?

Tags: html, css, html-email

It should work for `html email`, so I can't use `align-items` and `justify-content`

I want to let elements center on the same line, align left and right.

[image]

I have try to set `display: inline-block;` to let them in the same line, but `text-align: start` and `text-align: end` is not working.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 65%; background-color: pink">
  <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: start">
    <p>Left and Center</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: end">
    <p>Right and</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: end">
    <p>Center</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Display: table and Display: table-cell and add Vertical-align: middle.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Try with the below code:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; background-color: pink; display: table; table-layout: fixed;">
  <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: start; vertical-align: middle;">
    <p>Left and Center</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: end; vertical-align: middle;">
    <p>Right and</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: end; vertical-align: middle;">
    <p>Center</p>
  </div>
</div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOEI9.png
```

Comment: Tanks, it's working.

Comment: That won't work on MS Outlook desktop. Use an actual table